# Encoding CGPoint struct with NSCoder

Tags: cocoa

How do you encode and decode a `CGPoint` struct using `NSCoder`?

Comment: Just leaving this here for others. In Swift on MacOSX CGPoint is the same as NSPoint: 
public func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodePoint(myNSPoint, forKey: "someKeyName")
}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CGPoint`s and `NSPoint`s are both structures composed of two `CGFloat` values, so you can freely pass them around as each other.  The quick and dirty way would be:

```
NSCoder *myNSCoder;
CGPoint myPoint;
[myNSCoder encodePoint:*(NSPoint *)myPoint];
```

This will usually work, but it technically breaks the C99 strict aliasing rules.  If you want to be 100% compatible with the standard, you'll have to do something like:

```
typedef union
{
  CGPoint cgPoint;
  NSPoint nsPoint;
} CGNSPoint;

CGNSPoint cgnsPoint = { .cgPoint = myPoint };
[myNSCoder encodePoint:cgnsPoint.nsPoint];
```

Comment: However, if you’re building for the 64-bit runtime, or have NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64 defined to 1, NSPoint and CGPoint are typedefed to the same struct, so no casting or union shenanigans are required.

Comment: Furthermore, Foundation provides two inline functions named NSPoint{To,From}CGPoint. No need for pointer casting or a union.

Answer (score 26):

To encode:

```
CGPoint point = /* point from somewhere */
NSValue *pointValue = [NSValue value:&point withObjCType:@encode(CGPoint)];
[coder encodeObject:pointValue forKey:@"point"];
```

To decode:

```
NSValue *decodedValue = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"point"];
CGPoint point;
[decodedValue getValue:&point];
```

Comment: +1 This seems like a much better, less hackish general-purpose solution.

Comment: +1 BTW, you can use `(NSValue *)valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point` class method.

Answer (score 17):

Just an update for iOS developers. You can do the following in Cocoa Touch (but not in Cocoa):

```
[coder encodeCGPoint:myPoint forKey:@"myPoint"];
```

Comment: And you can decode with [aDecoder decodeCGPointForKey:@"myPoint"];