# How do I using NSCoding for a c-array of structs? (MKPolyline)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nscoding

I want to add NSCoding support to an c array of structs.  Specifically this is for a subclass of [`MKPolyline`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolyline_class/Reference/Reference.html), i.e. this is what I have to work with:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MKMapPoint *points;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger pointCount;

+ (MKPolyline *)polylineWithPoints:(MKMapPoint *)points count:(NSUInteger)count;
```

[I found a good answer on how to encode a *individual* struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448173/296446).  E.g.

```
NSValue* point = [NSValue value:&aPoint withObjCType:@encode(MKMapPoint)];
[aCoder encodeObject:point forKey:@"point"];

.... 

NSValue* point = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"point"];
[endCoordinateValue getValue:&aPoint];
```

Is there a nice way to apply this to a c Array - or will I simply have to iterate over the c-array?

Comment: How about `[NSValue value:aPointArray withObjCType:@encode(MKMapPoint[12])]` or similar?

Comment: @H2CO3 This method may be deprecated in a future release. You should use `valueWithBytes:objCType:` instead.

Comment: @voromax Didn't check the docs, just repeated what OP had, but true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: This approach only works if the data isn't going between processors with different "endian-ness". It should be safe going from iOS to iOS, certainly if only used on a given device.

You should be able to load the memory for the C-array into an `NSData` object then encode the `NSData` object.

```
MKMapPoint *points = self.points;
NSData *pointData = [NSData dataWithBytes:points length:self.pointCount * sizeof(MKMapPoint)];
[aCoder encodeObject:pointData forKey:@"points"];
```

Update: to get the data back:

```
NSData *pointData = [aCode decodeObjectForKey:@"points"];
MKMapPoint *points = malloc(pointData.length);
memcpy([pointData bytes], points);
self.points = points;
```

Comment: And this will nicely break portability (memdumping `float`s, ehh...)

Comment: Yes, if Apple starts using non-ARM chips there may be an issue going between big-endian and little-endian devices.

Comment: Should this portability issues be a concern, or is it unlikely to cause impact? Also how would you convert it back from `NSData` to a `MKMapPoint` array?

Comment: Im a little stuck again.... I made a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14914265/296446

Comment: This wasn't working for me for some reason and it also gave me a warning about sending const void* to void* parameter. I fixed it by using the following:

[pointData getBytes:& points length:pointsSize];